# How do I find a substring between two characters using Prolog?

Tags: string, list, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a variable being passed to a predicate that is a list of strings.

From each string in the list I want to extract the substring between the deepest set of parentheses and create a list of all of those substrings.

For example:

- Input:

  ```
  ["Canidae(Canis(C. lupus(C. l. familiaris)))", "Felidae(Felinae(Felis(F. catus)))", "Equidae(Equus(E. ferus(E. f. caballus)))"]
  ```
- Ouput:

  ```
  ["C. l. familiaris", "F. catus", "E. f. caballus"]
  ```

(I have used biological classification ranks as an example since they are similar in structure to my actual data)

Finally, the depth of each set of parentheses is unknown and the deepest substring is always the only substring between an open parentheses and a closed parentheses.

Thanks for your help with this, I'm new to Prolog so the way of thinking is a little different. I've been trying to get my head around this problem for a while but I can't work it out.

Comment: Is this homework? Are you allowed to use builtin predicates?

Comment: It's not homework, I am starting to learn Prolog at university and a similar problem to this was brought up in a lecture that I didn't know how to solve. I can use built-in predicates.  I am assuming it involves recursing through each string, finding the indexes of the deepest parentheses and using the built-in substring predicate to find the sub string between the deepest parentheses. I just don't know how I would go about recursing through each string to find the parentheses and then building a new list afterwards. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of solving the problem for a list, we better first solve the problem for a single string. In order to calculate the deepest substring, we can - if I understood the specifications correctly - calculate the position of the last opening parenthesis. We will assume you have transformed the string into a list of ASCII codes using for instance [`string_codes/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=string_codes/2). Here the opening bracket has code `40`:

```
last_opening(L,X) :-
    last_opening(L,0,0,X).

last_opening([],J,_,J).
last_opening([40|T],_,I,X) :-
    !,
    I1 is I+1,
    last_opening(T,I1,I1,X).
last_opening([_|T],J,I,X) :-
    I1 is I+1,
    last_opening(T,J,I1,X).
```

For example for your first example:

```
?- string_codes("Canidae(Canis(C. lupus(C. l. familiaris)))",L),last_opening(L,X).
L = [67, 97, 110, 105, 100, 97, 101, 40, 67|...],
X = 23.
```

It says we have to start extracting from position `23`:

```
Canidae(Canis(C. lupus(C. l. familiaris)))
                       ^ here
```

---

Once we know where the deepest substring starts, we can extract the string: we simply have to stop at the end of the list, or at code `41`, whatever comes first:

```
extract_substring(L,0,S) :-
    !,
    extract_substring2(L,S).
extract_substring([_|T],N,S) :-
    N1 is N-1,
    extract_substring(T,N1,S).

extract_substring2([],[]).
extract_substring2([41|_],[]) :-
    !.
extract_substring2([L|T],[L|U]) :-
    extract_substring2(T,U).
```

For example:

```
?- string_codes("Canidae(Canis(C. lupus(C. l. familiaris)))",L),last_opening(L,X),extract_substring(L,X,T),string_codes(St,T).
L = [67, 97, 110, 105, 100, 97, 101, 40, 67|...],
X = 23,
T = [67, 46, 32, 108, 46, 32, 102, 97, 109|...],
St = "C. l. familiaris".
```

---

Now we can write a predicate that does the `string_codes` calling automatically:

```
deepest_string(S,T) :-
    string_codes(S,CS),
    last_opening(CS,X),
    extract_substring(CS,X,CT),
    string_codes(T,CT).
```

For example:

```
?- deepest_string("Canidae(Canis(C. lupus(C. l. familiaris)))",L).
L = "C. l. familiaris".
```

---

To conclude we only have to implement the function over a list:

```
deepest_string_list([],[]).
deepest_string_list([S|ST],[T|TT]) :-
    deepest_string(S,T),
    deepest_string_list(ST,TT).
```

resulting in:

```
?- deepest_string_list(["Canidae(Canis(C. lupus(C. l. familiaris)))", "Felidae(Felinae(Felis(F. catus)))", "Equidae(Equus(E. ferus(E. f. caballus)))"],T).
T = ["C. l. familiaris", "F. catus", "E. f. caballus"].
```

If you want to alter the characters, you can simply lookup their ASCII equivalent and put these instead of `40` and `41`.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the solution and thanks again for explaining each step thoroughly and in good time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a DCG, and findall/3:

```
par(L, Content, R) -->
  left(L), inner(L, Content, R).

left(P) --> P.
left(P) --> [_], left(P).

inner(_, [], R) --> R.
inner(L, [C|Cs], R) -->
  \+ L, \+ R, [C], inner(L, Cs, R).

?- findall(A,(phrase(par("[",C,"]"),`[a[b][cd]]e`,_),atom_codes(A,C)),L).
L = [b, cd].
```

Note the `_` as last parameter of phrase/3. It enables list building by findall/3.

You can use any string as left/right parenthesis.

Comment: Building a grammar and use its parser is indeed a nice way to this problem. +1 :)

Comment: I haven't used DCGs yet in Prolog. I shall look into them later today and then try this solution as well. Thanks for your contribution :)